# Storing a reference to a Google Map and using it later

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My application relies heavily on Google Maps. Considering the fact that using/displaying the maps beyond their free limit usage is quite expensive, I want to minimize the number of connections made my app to the Google server.

As stated in the Google Maps API documentation, I am creating a Google map using its constructor. Now if a user first visits a Map page and then visits few other pages of the app and comes back to the original Map page, I do not want that the app should connect to the Google server for the purpose of redisplaying the map. Rather the map displayed earlier should be redisplayed.

Is there any way to achieve this? Can we consider saving the map reference to the browser's local storage and then retrieve it later. But how will the map be redisplayed using the same map reference .. I am wondering.

Any ideas/help?

Comment: Have you tried to implement this yourself yet?

Comment: @ Thomas Smyth I made my viewpoint after reading this post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/ITV805W6ytg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps api does not provided a storage system. In fact, it is forbidden to store a map or a google service in order to reuse it without loading the api. This is the regulation:
[image]

You can consult the regulation on [the google api web site](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=fr#10-license-restrictions).

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Answer (score -2):

S.P.H.I.N.X is 100% correct you should not try to store your map instance, but more importantly if you have the correct framework in place for you application you won't need to worry about that. There are a number of ways to do this. A common is to you a framework like Vue.js to create a single page application that doesn't require the map to be reloaded for each request.

Comment: Correct, SPA is the answer. Unfortunately, my app is not a SPA. I am using a bit obsolete open source platform.

Comment: What framework are you constrained to? You did not list this as a limitation.

Comment: It is not a framework but a forum platform named NodeBB. https://nodebb.org/